# Initiate CSS animation on input:checked?

Tags: css

I've done this [Sliding Image Panels with CSS3](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/17/sliding-image-panels-with-css3/comment-page-3/) tutorial, and ran into a little issue with using `:checked` to initiate the animation. Here is the [official demo](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3SlidingImagePanels/), and this [is my take](http://bit.ly/y0rtdW) (webkit and mozilla for now).

The images changes on click, but the panels won’t slide, instead they slide on initial page-load, which seems to be what the CSS is telling it to do… Any ideas?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it was PEBCAK.

I had left a trailing comma at the end, like this - see that little comma at the end there? Bad me.

```
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-1:checked ~ .cr-bgimg div span:nth-child(1),
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-2:checked ~ .cr-bgimg div span:nth-child(2),
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-3:checked ~ .cr-bgimg div span:nth-child(3),
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-4:checked ~ .cr-bgimg div span:nth-child(4), {
```

thereby making the entire declaration block invalid.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing this:

```
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-1:checked ~ .cr-bgimg div span:nth-child(1), .cr-container input.cr-selector-img-2:checked ~ .cr-bgimg div span:nth-child(2), .cr-container input.cr-selector-img-3:checked ~ .cr-bgimg div span:nth-child(3), .cr-container input.cr-selector-img-4:checked ~ .cr-bgimg div span:nth-child(4) {
    -moz-animation: 0s ease 0s normal none 1 none;
    -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It led me to the solution - I hadn't miss that section, but it was invalid because of an extra comma.